# Index out of bound exception when using Strassen's Matrix Multiplication

Tags: java

I am trying to implement Strassen's Matrix Multiplication in the following manner (some of the variables are declared at the top of the class, but you get the idea of what they are):

```
     public double[][] multiplyStrassen(double[][] m, double[][] m2) {
        int n = m.length;

         double [][] result = new double[n][n];
         System.out.println("n = " + n);
        if(n == 1) {
            result[0][0] = m[0][0] * m2[0][0];

        } else {
            A11 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            A12 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            A21 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            A22 = new double[n/2][n/2];

            B11 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            B12 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            B21 = new double[n/2][n/2];
            B22 = new double[n/2][n/2];

            partitionMatrices(m, A11, 0 , 0);
            partitionMatrices(m, A12, 0 , n/2);
            partitionMatrices(m, A21, n/2, 0);
            partitionMatrices(m, A22, n/2, n/2);

            partitionMatrices(m2, B11, 0 , 0);
            partitionMatrices(m2, B12, 0 , n/2);
            partitionMatrices(m2, B21, n/2, 0);
            partitionMatrices(m2, B22, n/2, n/2);

            P1 = multiplyStrassen(addMatrices(A11, A22), addMatrices(B11, B22));
            P2 = multiplyStrassen(addMatrices(A21, A22), B11);
            P3 = multiplyStrassen(A11, subMatrices(B12, B22));
            P4 = multiplyStrassen(A22, subMatrices(B21, B11));
            P5 = multiplyStrassen(addMatrices(A11, A12), B22);
            P6 = multiplyStrassen(subMatrices(A21, A11), addMatrices(B11, B12));
            P7 = multiplyStrassen(subMatrices(A12, A22), addMatrices(B21, B22));

            C11 = addMatrices(subMatrices(addMatrices(P1, P4), P5), P7);
            C12 = addMatrices(P3, P5);
            C21 = addMatrices(P2, P4);
            C22 = addMatrices(subMatrices(addMatrices(P1, P3), P2), P6);

            copyMatrix(C11, result, 0 , 0);
            copyMatrix(C12, result, 0 , n/2);
            copyMatrix(C21, result, n/2, 0);
            copyMatrix(C22, result, n/2, n/2);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void partitionMatrices(double[][] firstM, double[][] secondM, int A, int B) {
        for(int i1 = 0, i2 = A; i1 < secondM.length; i1++, i2++){
            for(int j1 = 0, j2 = B; j1 < secondM.length; j1++, j2++){
                secondM[i1][j1] = firstM[i2][j2];
            }
        }
    }
    public double[][] addMatrices(double[][] m1, double[][] m2) {
        int n = m1.length;
        double [][] result = new double[n][n];
        System.out.println("Printing m1: ");
        printGrid(m1.length, m1.length);
        System.out.println("Printing m2: ");
        printGrid(m2.length, m2.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                System.out.println("m1[i][j] = " + m1[i][j]);
                System.out.println("m2[i][j] = " + m2[i][j]);
                result[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public double [][] subMatrices(double [][] m1, double [][] m2) {
        int n = m1.length;

        double [][] result = new double[n][n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                result[i][j] = m1[i][j] - m2[i][j];

        return result;
    }

    public static void copyMatrix(double[][] firstM, double[][] secondM, int A, int B) {
        for(int i1 = 0, i2 = A; i1 < firstM.length; i1++, i2++){
            for(int j1 = 0, j2 = B; j1 < firstM.length; j1++, j2++){
                secondM[i2][j2] = firstM[i1][j1];
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
   at Matrix.addMatrices(Matrix.java:142)
   at Matrix.multiplyStrassen(Matrix.java:114)
   at MatrixMultiplicationTest.main(MatrixMultiplicationTest.java:20)
```

I understand that the line numbers aren't going to add up for you because I have other code in that class, but I'm just not sure where I went wrong since I'm just implementing an algorithm. The code runs for almost all of it and only seems to break in the end. I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: As an error says somewhere in the `Matrix.addMatrices` (line 142) you're trying to access some element that is outside of the range. Since your `Matrix.addMatrices` method looks ok, I guess matrices `m1` and `m2` are not of the same size. So you need to have a look at the other part of the code and check sizes (print them or debug) before each call. Also you have output of the matrices, try to look at the output more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, there should be some place in which you are trying to get a value from a zero sized array.It could be resulted from the expression:

```
int n = m.length;

double [][] result = new double[n][n];
```

which leads to an initialization of a zero sized array if n becomes zero.